# The BizTalk Purge & Archive Job now supports clean-up of orphaned instances

Tags: sql-server, powershell, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Recently applied BizTalk host-fix CU5 for BizTalk Server 2013 R2 (went well and working fine everything) : locking for BizTalk SQL agent job improvement having store procedure "dtasp_BackupAndPurgeTrackingDatabase" use for BizTalk Sql agent job "DTA Purge and Archive (BizTalkDTADb)" but it look like there was same store procedure what I have during installation first time.

As per some good BizTalk blogger have mention that MS BizTalk hotfix CU5 now supports clean-up of orphaned instances. Below SQL (SP) script found after CU5 hotfix applied and It's same as previous installation.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dtasp_BackupAndPurgeTrackingDatabase]
@nLiveHours tinyint, --Any completed instance older than the live hours +live days
@nLiveDays tinyint = 0, --will be deleted along with all associated data
@nHardDeleteDays tinyint = 0, --all data older than this will be deleted.
@nvcFolder nvarchar(1024) = null, --location for .bak backup files to be put
@nvcValidatingServer sysname = null,
@fForceBackup int = 0 -- if this flag is set to 1 we will force a backup at 
that point
AS
```

I  haven't seen the new parameter value was added during CU5 hotfix...as mention on

[The BizTalk Purge & Archive Job now supports clean-up of orphaned instances](https://pvandenheede.wordpress.com/2017/09/19/the-biztalk-purge-archive-job-now-supports-clean-up-of-orphaned-instances/)

Any one have suggestion how we do configure new parameter value for DTA Purge and Archive (BizTalkDTADb) ?

Additionally Using powershell script to find BizTalk Cumulative Update installed in this machine:
(available on-- [Check all BizTalk Cumulative Updates installed in server with PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Check-all-BizTalk-1b0886b5)
)

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\BizTalk\Downloads\CheckAllCUInstalled.ps1
```

This is the list of BizTalk Cumulative Update installed in this machine: DIPENBIZTALK
- Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2 CU5

So BizTalk server 2013 R2 CU5 successfully applied on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Article this feature appeared for BizTalk 2013 R2 in CU6, for BizTalk 2013 it was CU5. So you should be installing CU6 rather than CU5.  You should always be installing the latest CU which you can find at [Service Pack and cumulative update list for BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2555976/service-pack-and-cumulative-update-list-for-biztalk-server)

As to where to configure it, it would be in the SQL Agent Job **BizTalk DTA Purge and Archive**, mentioned in that article, that calls that stored procedure.

Comment: (@fHardDeleteRunningInstances int = 0 --if this flag is set to 1 we will delete all the running service instances older than hard delete days
AS)

(exec @ret = dtasp_PurgeTrackingDatabase /*nHours*/@nLiveHours, /*nDays*/@nLiveDays, /*nHardDeleteDays*/@nHardDeleteDays, /*dtLastBackup*/@dtLastArchiveDate, /*fHardDeleteRunningInstances*/@fHardDeleteRunningInstances)
--This is difference we will see between old and new SQL SP after CU6 installed for BizTalk 2013 R2 version.